# Change order of polynomial data

Tags: rapidminer

When importing data to Rapidminer, I have a column of polynomial data. ("very low", "low", "medium", "high" and "very high"). When I display this data the order does not make much sense to me (low --> very low --> very high --> high --> medium)(see screenshot below).

[image: Order of polynomial data is not in a logical order]

Is it possible to tell Rapidminer in which order these data should be displayed? If not, what is the best workaround to get the data ordered? (For instance: Shall I replace all "very low" with 0's?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order RapidMiner encounters polynominal values dictates the order they are plotted. Mapping values won't help for the basic plotter (the advanced plotter is different and understands sorting). An ugly solution would be to contrive to force RapidMiner to see the values in the order they should be plotted. A more advanced solution would be to create a Groovy script to get into the example set and allow the implicit ordering to be changed.

Thinking of the ugly solution more, perhaps you could map the values so they could be sorted alphabetically (use the `Map` operator), write the example set out to a file and read it back in again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For the data set I currently have, I might be able to just change the order of the rows (making "very low" appear first, etc.)